# Change Color of Selected Option in <select multiple>

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm having this problem where I need to change the color of a/multiple option element(s) when clicked/ selected. Default color is blue when clicked, I believe we should have a solution for this now since I've try to search for solutions but to no avail. Hoping to do this in CSS or vanilla JS. no libraries or frameworks.

[Link to sample code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRUJC0SJJ7LH)

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```css
select[multiple]:focus option:checked {
  background: red linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, red 100%);
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2" selected>two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice! What is the os/browser/device support like for this?

Comment: Plus, any explanation why this seems to need `background: red linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, red 100%)`? (`background: red` only doesn’t seem to do the trick, at least in Chrome.)

Comment: Actually, you only need `background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, red 0%, red 100%);`. You can't change the background color because it is set by the browser with `!important`. But setting background image works.

Comment: Is there a way to change text color of selected item and the background color when out of focus?