# Change multiple Option Selection Focus Color in Select Tag in html

Tags: html, css

Hello i have Refer following question

[Change the select tag active / focus color after selection of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50904205/change-the-select-tag-active-focus-color-after-selection-of-options)

my Question is that, can we change focus color of single selection when i have Multiple Select tag currently show blue color.

[image]

when i select option, selection color is blue..can we change that color..?

Comment: You can do it by giving a class to option tag. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12836286/10759347).

Comment: You might have to go with a custom select plugin like [select2](https://select2.org/) if you want to have full control over styling across browsers

Comment: @Marfee It is Not working

Comment: i got it from from Following link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50618702/8558398